# Shared global immutable objects in D

Tags: thread-safety, constants, immutability, d, shared-memory

Is it safe to make a global (module scope) immutable object `shared`? Should I use `shared` or `__gshared` (as it seems for me safe too)?

Comment: Immutable objects can be safely shared among threads, so there is no need to specify the `shared` storage class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dlang.org/articles/migrate-to-shared.html says:

> Immutable data doesn't have synchronization problems, so the compiler doesn't place it in TLS.

("TLS" is thread local storage.)

So, it does not matter whether the immutable object is declared as shared.

For brevity, we can omit `shared` in this case.